# Python, Checking if any elements in a list are contained in another list

Tags: python

From the codingbat webpage, from list 1 python, it asks me to write a definition where it returns true if an array of two elements contains the numbers 2 or 3, I wrote:

```
def has23(nums):
    for i in range(nums):
      if i == 2 or i ==3:
         return True
      else:
         return False
```

But it seems to be unable to cope with `has23([4, 3])` where it returns `False`. I already know the solution (thanks to the python community people) but I really can't understand what is wrong with the definition I wrote.

Could please someone help with that one?

Comment: You don't need the range

Comment: This doesn't return False when given a list, it blows up because `range()` doesn't take a list as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are simply checking the first value and then returning `True` or `False`. Instead do it as follows:

**1)**

```
def has23(nums):
    if (2 in nums) or (3 in nums):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**2)** `@Ricardo` suggested: `return (2 in nums) or (3 in nums)`

**3)** `@thefourtheye` suggested: `return len(set(nums) & {2, 3}) > 0`

**4)** `@thefourtheye` also suggested `return set(nums).isdisjoint({2, 3})`

**5)** `@RemcoGerlich` suggested `return any(i == 2 or i == 3 for i in nums)`

**6)** or if you want to use your type of loop:

```
def has23(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if i == 2 or i == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

## [NOTE]

I was testing this question with lambda and here is a way to test for any number of checks:
This checks whether any element from `to_check` is in `lst`

**7)**

```
>>> lst = [1,2,4,7,4,10,53,76,45,354,654,434,32]
>>> to_check = [3,4,9,96,23]
>>> print any(map(lambda i: i in lst, to_check))
True
```

I know this is not directly related to your question, but it might be something to look at. Quite nifty.

Another way:

**8)**

`>>> print len(set(bar) & set(to_check)) > 0`

Comment: that could be simplified to just: `return (2 in nums) or (3 in nums)`

Comment: Even better `return len(set(nums) & {2, 3}) > 0`

Comment: Thank you people for your brilliant additions. :)

Comment: @user3480623, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks. And lots of thanks to all the contributions. :)

Comment: @sshashank124 Actually `return set(nums).isdisjoint({2, 3})` should be even faster than the first version I suggested.

Comment: @user3480623, I have added another section to my answer. Might be worth a look at. :)

Comment: Amusingly, I would write this yet another way: `return any(i == 2 or i == 3 for i in nums)`.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, Your suggestion has been added. :) Turning into quite the `wiki`

Answer (score 0):

there is indeed a problem with your code:

```
for i in range(nums):
```

`nums` is a list, so you can't use `range` with it. You can use `range(len(num))` and then check `num[0]`, `num[1]`, etc. ie

```
if (nums[i]==2) or (nums[i]==3):
```

But you can just do:

```
for i in nums:
    if ((i==2) or (i==3)):
```

Which will indeed browse all the values in `nums`.

You don't need to browse all the value and check with:

```
if (2 in nums) or (3 in nums):
```

Finally, you can skip the test and simply do:

```
return ((2 in nums) or (3 in nums))
```

Comment: First of all thank you for answering, have tried with just           for i in nums:
    if ((i==2) or (i==3)):                                                But it doesn't work

Comment: Is the CPython interpreter clever enough to optimize `((2 in nums) or (3 in nums))` into a single scan over the array?